# In Emacs dired, how to find/visit multiple files?

Tags: emacs, dired

If I have multiple files marked, how do I find/visit all those marked files in emacs, beside running `dired-find-file` on each of them?

Is there a build-in command, or do I need some extra lisp code?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you add this to your .emacs, you'll be able to open the files via the keybinding 'F'.

```
(eval-after-load "dired"
  '(progn
     (define-key dired-mode-map "F" 'my-dired-find-file)
     (defun my-dired-find-file (&optional arg)
       "Open each of the marked files, or the file under the point, or when prefix arg, the next N files "
       (interactive "P")
       (let* ((fn-list (dired-get-marked-files nil arg)))
         (mapc 'find-file fn-list)))))
```

Obviously you can just override the built-in 'f' if you want.

Comment: Thanks for this! Small stylistic point but you don't need to use `let*` in this case (`let` is sufficient). And really we could probably just simplify that last form to `(mapc 'find-file (dired-get-marked-files nil arg))`.

Answer (score 37):

In Emacs 23.2 and higher, the `dired-x.el` module is available, and it gives you access to a command that does exactly what you want. After you load it (just `(load "dired-x")`, normally), you'll be able to invoke the function `dired-do-find-marked-files`. Here's its built-in documentation:

```
(dired-do-find-marked-files &optional NOSELECT)

Find all marked files displaying all of them simultaneously.
With optional NOSELECT just find files but do not select them.

The current window is split across all files marked, as evenly as possible.
Remaining lines go to bottom-most window.  The number of files that can be
displayed this way is restricted by the height of the current window and
`window-min-height'.

To keep dired buffer displayed, type C-x 2 first.
To display just marked files, type C-x 1 first.
```

So after `dired-x` is loaded, you can just use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `dired-do-find-marked-files` <kbd>RET</kbd> and you'll get exactly what your question asks for: all marked files will be visited as though you'd run `dired-find-file` on all of them.

Comment: My dired-mode doesn't recognize this command, and I'm on 23.4

Comment: @Bruce Connor: probably You don't have dired-x installed. Try to add `(add-hook 'dired-load-hook (function (lambda () (load "dired-x"))))` in `.emacs`.

Comment: 'F' key is keyboard shortcut for dired-do-find-marked-files, at least in Emacs 24.4.

Comment: I will also add that you can use a prefix argument to prevent Emacs from splitting the frame into a new window for each file opened.  So for example, you can use `C-u M-x dired-do-find-marked-files`, or alternatively `C-u C-F` to use the default keybinding.

Answer (score 6):

You could try [dired+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) which provides many extensions to dired including the ability to select multiple files and find/view all of them.