# find several files with one command in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I would like to know Emacs' equivalent of Vim's :n, which opens
several files according to a glob.

Say I have this directory:

-rw-rw-r-- 1 pablo pablo   31 Jun 25 00:59 /home/pablo/tmp/prueba.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pablo pablo 2442 May  9  1913 /home/pablo/tmp/sin_soap.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pablo pablo  726 Jun 25 15:20 /home/pablo/tmp/verificar.php

And I want to open all those files.  In Vim, I can type

:n *php

and that will give me one buffer for every file; I don't know how to
do that in Emacs (when it's already open, of course I can do 'emacs
*php' in a shell).

I'm happy with a function that I can call from any buffer via M-x, but
if there's a command that I can call in dired-mode (say, edit all
marked files or something), that would be beyond cool.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The ordinary `find-file` command, <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd>, will accept wildcards and open multiple buffers.  From the documentation:

> Interactively, or if wildcards is non-nil in a call from Lisp,
> expand wildcards (if any) and visit multiple files.  You can
> suppress wildcard expansion by setting `find-file-wildcards' to nil.

In your example you'd just type <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd>`*php`<kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: Dude.  I had no idea.  I've been wanting to be able to do that for *years*.

Comment: That's what I get for using ido-find-file instead... Also, I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110118/in-emacs-dired-how-to-find-visit-multiple-files

Comment: If you use `ido-find-file`, you can do `C-x C-f ~/path/to/somewhere/*.txt`, but instead of pressing return, press `C-x C-f` to start the regular find-file with the current input

Answer (score 0):

Open the directory in dired, or use find-dired to create a dired buffer using Unix find (i.e. not `find-file`), then mark the files you want (with `m`) to open and press `F`.

Comment: The F is normally unbound in regular dired-mode.  However, I bound it to the defun I found in the question I posted in the comment above.

Comment: This requires dired-x.  A simple 

    (require 'dired-x)

does it.